# Spring is not working for my Rails 6 app when trying a Rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring-boot, ruby-on-rails-6

Based on [spring's document](https://github.com/rails/spring) when I try to run a command like `bin/rails routes && spring status` the spring status should change the next time it runs, but no matter how many times I try that command the `spring`'s status does not change, BUT when I try to edit a file it's status changes. And also my rails running time is very slow (make sense since the `spring` does not work over my app!).

This is an output sample of `bin/rails routes 1>/dev/null && spring status` execution:

```sh
$ bin/rails routes 1>/dev/null && spring status
Spring is running:

 6297 spring server | proj | started 1 hour ago
15304 spring app    | proj | started 23 mins ago | development mode
17620 spring app    | proj | started 8 mins ago | development mode
```

This is an output sample of `touch config/application.rb && spring status` execution (notice the last line's start time!):

```sh
$ touch config/application.rb && spring status
Spring is running:

 6297 spring server | proj | started 1 hour ago
15304 spring app    | proj | started 24 mins ago | development mode
18841 spring app    | proj | started 1 sec ago | development mode
```

#### Questions:

1. Why `spring` is not working when I execute a command?
2. How to make `spring` working to reduce my rails' execution time?

Comment: First thing I do in every new app I'm building is remove spring...

Comment: @jvillian And why? Our life's time is precious.

Comment: Yes, and now I never lose time futzing with spring or having to ask questions about it on SO.

Comment: I see that the documentation says it should restart spring when you run rails routes, but it doesn't really make much sense for spring to restart itself just because you view the routes, since nothing changed.  Maybe the documentation is wrong in this case and spring isn't supposed to restart.

Comment: @dariush spring causes more problems than it solves. I’m with jvillian— step 1 in a new project is to remove spring. When spring goes wrong it will look like any number of other unrelated issues and you can lose hours troubleshooting something that never would have happened without it. It’s buggy garbage.

Answer (score 0):

This is what made it worked for me:

```
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

Source: https://github.com/rails/spring#walkthrough